# SQL server 2008 Enterprise Edition - Dual X5670 Processors Support

Tags: sql-server, sql

Would SQL server 2008 Enterprise Edition fully support Dual X5670 Processors which is equal to 24 core at total. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OBVIOUSLY (as per system requirements etc.) the only answer is yes.

Make sure, though, you have a LOT of memory and a LOT of IO budget (i.e. many fast discs), otherwsie in most cases most processors wil lbe idle waiting for the discs to finish.

Most of the time, CPU is like the lowest taxed area of a database server.

Comment: thanks for replay. i also bought 24 GB ram and 4x raid 10 sas 15k harddrives. what do you say ?

Comment: Ah - realize you bought bad. Really. 24 cores - I would not go for less than 48gb ram. And seriously, if we talk discs, we should talk about a DOZEN or more. I run a quad core 8 gb virtual machine sql server. DATA is on a 6x10k RAID 10, logs and tempdb separate - and I have mostly problems getting more than 25% cpu load because the discs max out. I would say you ahve a serious problem on the disc side that will most likely make the cpu go waiting. Especially with only 24gb ram.

Comment: A lot depends, though, on what you do data wise. Usage patterns trump. Olap or OLTP? Data warehouse? Small or large working set. I have seen a server max out 8 cores with 8gb ram because the active set, queried tens of thousands of times per second, was only about 4gb large (financial data).

Comment: well i will also run web farm on this server. so i do not think so cpu will have time to wait idle :) i have queries getting executed millions of times per day ^^

Comment: If you're running all of this on the same box, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: yes they will run in the same box . why i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Because you pertty much get two systems in competition to each other. 2 smaller boxes would have been better. And one for databases - with a lot of discs.

Comment: well that is why i have 24 core.

Comment: No no no no no no no. For production systems that you expect to see *any* kind of load on at all, keep the app tier and the DB tier on different hardware. Once you start to hit a performance limit, you can easily measure *what* the bottleneck is and fix it. If it's CPU on the app tier, add another app server or webserver. If it's IOPS on the DB tier, you need to start fixing your DB or your storage. If all of this is on the same box, you're in an absolute mess.

Comment: @PokemonCraft - go back to learning basics. Your 24 cores are not even having enough RMA to properly work in most scenarios. And the discs are too small for even a small db server alone. Having much cpu power is not the answer for most questions in databases.

Comment: what is RMA TomTom

Comment: @TomTom has an unfortunate tendency for typographical errors. He meant RAM.

Answer (score 3):

[Enterprise](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2019) can support up to 8 physical CPU's so yes.
SQL Server [supports NUMA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms180954%28v=sql.105%29) so you should be good.  From what I've heard you should also leave HT turned ON for these processors, unlike the previous recommendation which was to switch it off.

Comment: thanks for replay. i would give vote up but do not have enough reputation yet :D